# Finding combination of coins that can produce a given sum

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

This function is checking, whether it has enough money in a list called `self.deviceMoney` to make change.

It works exactly the way I want, but only in case where not many coins are in `self.deviceMoney`. The algorithm is checking, if the list has enough coins to create some number, if yes remove that many coins from list.

Example

```
Number = 8
self.deviceMoney=[1,3,4,5,2]
```

Now, we can create this number from `[3,4,1]` or `[5,3]` etc.

List after operation `self.deviceMoney == [5,2]`

When I put into this list for example 200 coins, my program stops responding. I think, because a large amount of `itertools.combinations`. How can I optimize this function or resolve this problem to make the algorithm much better?

```
def changeOperation(self):
    self.deviceMoney.sort()
    tmpChange=int(self.change*100)
    tmp=set()
   # print(self.change)
    print(self.deviceMoney)

    if self.change > 0:
        for i in range(1,len(self.deviceMoney)):
            for j in itertools.combinations(self.deviceMoney,i):
                if sum(j) == tmpChange:
                    tmp.add(tuple(j))
                    print("tmp.append(list(j)): " +str(tmp))

        if tmp:
            a = next(iter(tmp))
            print("a: " + str(a))
            print("a[0]= ",a[0])
            for k in range(len(a)):
                self.deviceMoney.remove(a[k])

            print("deviceMoney: "+str(self.deviceMoney))

            self.errorMessageBox("some string"))
        else:
            self.errorMessageBox("some string")
            self.deviceMoney=[]

    elif self.change == 0:
        self.errorMessageBox("some string")

    else:
        pass

 #prints for tests
```

Comment: You create all the possible combinations and then you just use the first one. Seems you could just calculate the first one. But there's one possibly bigger issue which I guess is not really what it seems: If no combination was found, you "empty" the `deviceMoney` list (more specifically you assign a new empty list to `self.deviceMoney`).

Comment: You should check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum). That might help